# Friends Missing From Facebook List

Tags: facebook, facebook-friends

I currently have 370 friends. However, when I go to my friends list and count by hand, there are only 365.  I assume this is because five friends have "blocked" me.

How do I determine who these five people are?

There are many answers to the question, "how can I tell if someone has blocked me?" which is *not* what I need.

If I knew who these five missing people were, then I could just try a search and see if they pop up in the results, or use the mutual friend method.  The reason this doesn't work is because *I don't know what name to search!*

I just need to be able to see all 370 friends on my list and then I can figure it out from there.

In addition, there is a person that I know, but I'm not currently friends with.  It says that we have 113 friends in common.  However, when I look at his page, right beneath his photo it says that I have 108 friends in common.

Hmmmm...that's a difference of *five*!  Quite a coincidence!

Who are these five people? It's most likely the exact same five people that I cannot see on my friends list because they have blocked me...but again, *who are they*?

Is it possible to view my activity log since the first day I signed up?

I could comb through that and see every single time I became friends with someone.

Is that something that I can access, and if so, where/how?

Answer (score 1):

About most of your question, you can't find them if they blocked you, unless you have some kind of list to compare to and find the differences.

> how can I tell if someone has blocked me?

It's actually what you mean. You know someone blocked you, but you don't know whom. I'm also not sure if those apps actually work or just try to collect data, never tried those.

---

The best shot you got is to compare the friend list, in my opinion. But I don't know if people who blocked you would appear there normally.

You could create yourself another account, be friend with, and let it block the original you - then, check the activity log to see if the ".. now friend with.." is still there.

[Here is the filter of Added Friends](https://www.facebook.com/me/allactivity?privacy_source=activity_log&log_filter=cluster_8), it will show only activities related to adding friends, sending friend requests etc.